# Issue with creating Evergreen Product in unit tests

Tags: cpq

I have an issue with unit testing a piece of logic built for [Evergreen Subscriptions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_evergreen_parent.htm). When trying to insert Evergreen product I get following:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Can't save Product.
>   Evergreen Subscriptions are not enabled.: []

Evergreen Subscriptions are enabled in managed package (v. 220.10) configuration. Evergreens are working normally and even the same code fired in dev console runs without such issues.

Here is the piece of logic causing issues:

```
this.products = new List<Product2>{
    new Product2(
        Name = 'Test',
        IsActive = true,
        Family = 'License', 
        PricingCycle__c = 'Monthly',
        SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = isEvergreen ? 'Evergreen' : 'Renewable'
    )
};
insert this.products;
```

Comment: If CPQ manages Evergreen Subscription settings in a Custom Setting, then your test class will need to mock this as custom settings have no values in testmethods (unless you use `seeAllData=true` which I heartily don't recommend)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I don't think CPQ stores configuration in any publicly accessible custom setting

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by [disabling CPQ Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_disable_apex_triggers.htm) as below:

```
this.products = new List<Product2>{
    new Product2(
        Name = 'Test',
        IsActive = true,
        Family = 'License', 
        PricingCycle__c = 'Monthly',
        SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = isEvergreen ? 'Evergreen' : 'Renewable'
    )
};
SBQQ.TriggerControl.disable();
insert this.products;
SBQQ.TriggerControl.enable();
```

Not sure if that's the best way, though. If you have a better idea please post your answer.